# How to make AjaxForm work with several forms loaded using jquery load()?

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I have a page with a  div that is dynamically filled using a paginator ;-) At page init I load the first 10 forms in it using jquery .load() method.

What I'd like to do is to make all the forms dynamically updatable using AjaxForm plugin. I know about server side, let's call it update.asp. It works.

But there are several questions:

1. How to make plugin work in the first place as the AjaxForm seems not to work to the firms inside a dynamically loaded div?
2. How do I ID and name the forms? Now I used ID and name myForm to all of them (maybe that is why it doesn't work). Because if I use name myForm1, myForm2 etc... I have to write 10 ajaxForm functions that I use:

   ```
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm({
          beforeSubmit: showLoader,
          success: hideLoader
    });
   ```

I would then need to make this 10 times using myForm1 to myForm10? There must be another way...

3. How do I make AjaxForm work with the pages that are not loaded yet? I think this is the same problem as 1). Because even page 1 is loaded dynamically somehow the ajaxForm doesn't get bind to the form.

Sorry, I am quite new to jquery,  I am trying hard to study it, I tried this quite some time before I wrote here. If you can help me, I'd be very gratefull.

Yours

Jerry

EDIT: Here is my loader now... It is not working OK, as the loader is never shown, it dissapears so fast I can see it only if I put alert in the hideLoader :-(((

```
      function load(num){
      showLoader2();
      var link='/obdelaneslike.asp?ID=<%=request.QueryString("IDRecept") %>&offset='+ num
       $('#content').load(link, function(){
        hideLoader2();
        $('.ajax-loader').hide();

         $('.myForm').bind("submit", function(event) { 
                   $(this).ajaxForm({

               beforeSubmit: showLoader($(this).find('img.ajax-loader').attr('id')),
           success: hideLoader($(this).find('img.ajax-loader').attr('id'))

           }); 
           return false;
                  }); 

           });

       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try and address these one at a time to better match the question:

**1)** You can re-bind when you `.load()` (or whatever jQuery ajax method you're using) or use a plugin like [`livequery()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery), for example here's re-binding (do this in your `success` handler):

```
$("#myDynamicDiv .myForm").ajaxForm({ ...options... });
```

Or using [`livequery()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery):

```
$(".myForm").livequery(function() { $(this).ajaxForm({ ...options... }); });
```

**2)** Use a class instead of IDs here, like this: `class="myForm"`, whenever you want to handle batches of elements like this `class` is a pretty safe route.  The examples above work with class and not IDs per form (they can have IDs, they're just not used). Your form tags would look like this:

```
<form class="myForm">
```

**3)** The same solutions in answer #1 account for this :)

Comment: Hi there again and again thanx for your help... Right before your answer I tried one more thing: $('#myForm').live("submit", function(event) { $(this).ajaxSubmit({ .... and it WORKS. Thanx for the tip of not using ID's. It is wrong the form has same ID's although it works.

I am just wondering what is the main difference on my live("submit") and your livequery?

Comment: @Jerry2 - You're just attaching the ajax form before the submit action finishes...this works but your `beforeSend` may be affected, as it would serialize data at the wrong time IIRC.  I would definitely avoid multiple IDs though, they can cause other issues...you can stick with what you have just use classes and `$('.myForm').live()` :)

Comment: So your solution of livequery is better to use in this situation?

Comment: @Jerry2 - It's a catch-all solution, the *optimal* way to do this is binding after your do your load in the `success` callback/handler.  If you're unable, `.livequery()` is a decent fallback :)

Comment: I can bind after I do the load, yes. So after each load I use bind for forms, not live?

Comment: What happens to the old forms that dissapear, are they automatically unbinded?

Comment: @Jerry2 - How are you loading the content?  If you call `.empty()` before the `.load()` it'll unbind everything appropriately :)

Comment: I have edited my post to show the whole loader. It loads the contents div with new data that has 3 forms and binds the AjaxForm to the new forms that are loaded. My problem is that the loader is never shown. I tried with alert before hide() and then it is shown. So I guess it is not shown because it doesn't wait till the form is submitted, but I properly used the sucess callback ;-(

Comment: Also first time I click on submit in form it doesn't work. From the second time it works :-(

Answer (score 1):

ID values are unique to a single DOM element. So you'd need to give each form a new ID, so if you had three forms, you could name them like so:

```
<form name="formone" id="formone"...
<form name="formtwo" id="formtwo"...
<form name="formthree" id="formthree"...
```

Now you'd create instances of your ajax request like so:

```
     $('#formone, #formtwo, #formthree').ajaxForm({
       beforeSubmit: showLoader,
       success: hideLoader
     });
```

Comment: Alternatively, all forms could have the same CLASS, for example .myform and then you'd bind the ajax event to the class, like so:

$('.myform').ajaxForm...

Comment: Thanx! This doesn't save my need to make live binding though (Nick's solution does however).