# how to rename file with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

For a filemanagement i use a form to rename the files which are displayed via a foreach loop.

First the php:

```
if(isset($_POST['rename'])) {
    if(!is_dir($_POST['old_name'])) {
       rename($_POST['old_name'], $NewFileName);
       exit;
    }
}
```

the form:

```
<form class="sfmform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="old_name" value="<?php echo $dir.'/'.$file; ?>" />
        <input class="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" placeholder="only a-z, A-Z and 0-9" value="" />
        <input type="submit" class="rename" name="rename" value="Go" />      

    </form>
```

Note: the form is part of the foreach loop and is near each file

The js (ajaxForm):

```
 $('.sfmform').ajaxForm({

    success: function(data) {
        status.html(data);
        $('.myFiles').load(document.URL +  ' .myFiles');

    },

});
```

The div .myFiles contains the rendered files with in it the foreach loop.

What happens:
The fist rename goes correct; without a hard refresh he renames the files and it is immediately visible because the div .myFiles is loaded.
But the second rename goes wrong; he follows the loop in php and dies.
I f i do not use an exit; in the php, he generates myFiles div several times.

When i do a hard refresh; i can rename again. But renaming twice after each other without a hard refresh, he dies.

What i am doing wrong?

I also have other forms for making directory with the same class: sfmfom and these are not part of the foreach loop. With them, i have no problem to use them twice after each other.
Why is this happening only with the form which are part of the foreach loop?
How can i make this work correctly?

Update: foreach

```
/* RENDER THE FILES */
foreach ($files as $file) {
if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') { // don't show links to previous folders
    $MimeFileType = mime_content_type($dir.'/'.$file);
    $FileExtension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $ClassExtension = 'sfm_'.$FileExtension;

.......
<td>
    <!-- RENAME -->
    <form class="sfmform" method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="old_name" value="<?php echo $dir.'/'.$file; ?>" />
        <input class="new_name" type="text" name="new_name" placeholder="only a-z, A-Z and 0-9" value="" />
        <input type="submit" class="rename" name="rename" value="Go" />      

    </form>

</td>
}
}
```

Comment: Just wait until someone starts submitting `old_name=/etc/passwd` and other fun paths to your script!

Comment: what loop in php? and as @jszobody said: this code is extraordinarily dangerous - you're allowing a user to specify **ANY** file/path for which they know the name of on your server. that opens you up to theft of pretty much every file on the machine.

Comment: @jszobody  I know the issue of manipulating the old name. But that is protected elsewhere! But that is not my question...

Comment: "he follows the loop in php and dies". As @MarcB said, ¿what loop in PHP? Post it to take a look at it.

Comment: Personally, I'd recommend that rather than move actual files on your filesystem, you update the links in a database.

Your problem most likely with needing a refresh, however, is that the jQuery action isn't bound to the dynamically loaded form. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467894/how-to-make-ajaxform-work-with-several-forms-loaded-using-jquery-load for some insight into that

Comment: foreach added above. It seems that the problem is that the form is in the foreach. All other forms (outside the foreach) i have no problem with the ajax

Comment: Solution already found! This: `$(".sfmform").livequery(function() { $(this).ajaxForm({` instead of this: `$('.sfmform').ajaxForm({` solved the problem! Thanks @Steve

Answer (score 0):

Solution found:

The js should be this:

```
$(".sfmform").livequery(function() { $(this).ajaxForm({
```

instead of this:

```
$('.sfmform').ajaxForm({
```